# min and max attributes for date not working in angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

dynamic min and max attributes not taking in ionic2 'datetime-local' type.

```
<ion-input value="" type="datetime-local" [formControl]="expdate" [attr.min]="mindate" [attr.max]="maxdate"></ion-input>
```

### ts file

```
export class CollectMoneyPage{
  mindate:any;
  maxdate:any;
  constructor(){ 
    this.maxdate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,-5);
    this.mindate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,-5);  
  }
}
```

But it was working fine in the following way,

```
<ion-input value="" type="datetime-local" [formControl]="expdate" min="2016-12-21T02:44:14" max="2016-12-21T02:44:14"></ion-input>
```

Comment: try without toISOString()

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if datetime-local is a valid type of ion-input.
Try:

```
<ion-datetime value="" [formControl]="expdate" [min]="mindate" [max]="maxdate"></ion-datetime>
```

More [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)